# Buildozer stuck at command: buildozer android debug

Tags: ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

Versions
Python: 2.7.15
OS: Ubuntu 18.10

I'm trying to create an apk file. I created a virtual box with ubuntu. Now the terminal of ubuntu is stuck after the command: buildozer android debug.

What can I do to make it work?

[image: This is where buildozer gets stuck]

This is when I use the command: buildozer android logcat

[image: This is when I use the command: buildozer android logcat]

I tried a lot of commands and now the terminal is stuck again:

[image]

I tried to install the Android SDK in order to move forward, with the following command: sudo apt update && sudo apt install android-sdk

But the terminal give me the error in the screenshot above.

I'm seriously thinking about learning java and use android studio. What do you think about it?

p.s. the log_level in the buildozer file is already equal to 2.

Comment: I don't believe that it is stuck. To show the full log, in your *buildozer.spec*, change `log_level` from *1* to *2*. Retry `buildozer android debug `

Answer (score 0):

## Solution - Missing adb

Install the latest platform tools (which includes adb and fastboot) and the SDK tools for API level 28:

1. Change directory, `cd ~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin`
2. Run `sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"`

## Note

To show the full log, in your *buildozer.spec*, change `log_level` from *1* to *2*. Retry *buildozer android debug*.

```
log_level = 2
```